# Simulate wait's command -n flag in zsh

Tags: zsh, wait

I am creating two shell jobs as follows

```
sleep 5 &
completion_pid=$!

sleep 40 && exit 1 &
failure_pid=$!
```

In `bash` I am able to get the exit code of the first job to finish by using the `-n` flag of `wait`'s command

```
# capture exit code of the first subprocess to exit
wait -n $completion_pid $failure_pid
```

It seems however that this flag is not available in my MacOS Big Sur's version of `wait` (probably cause I am using `zsh` - ? )

```
▶ wait -n
wait: job not found: -n
```

Are there any alternative tools to do this that are also available on `MacOS`?

What perhaps is weird is that I am getting the same error when invoking a script containing `wait -n` as `bash myscript.sh`...

Comment: `wait -n` was a relatively new addition to `bash` (introduced in 4.3). Are you using an older version of `bash`? (And regarding your original question, I'm not aware of any simple way to simulate `wait -n` in `zsh`.)

Comment: thanks, you were right about the `bash` version; upgrading it allows me to at leas run my script with `bash` interpreter

Answer (score -1):

Since you are waiting by specifying PIDs, you can simply do a

```
 wait $completion_pid $failure_pid
```

Comment: This will wait until even the last job of the two has exited; I think `-n` will wait until the first has exited

Comment: Indeed, you are right. I didn't recognize this from my first reading of the bash man page.....